# Opening squeezebox in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, squeezebox

I need to open the `squeezebox` in the middle of the screen. I'm using joomla and this is the line of code that is giving me problems:

```
<a class="modal" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/tGKATMITCnA?rel=0&wmode=opaque&autoplay=1&controls=0" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 480, y: 270}, onClose: function() {}}">video</a>
```

The popup opens at the top of the screen, rather than in the middle as expected.

Comment: Could you add code or a reference to the page containing the error?

Comment: @SaschaM78 - I've submitted an edit where I fixed the formatting so you should see it soon.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing?  The SqueezeBox JSON formatting looks correct and the default placement is to be centered on the screen, so should be working...